# moving a div - styled cursor:move

Tags: javascript, css, html, cursor

I have a div for which i have set the cursor:move style. The div shows up as a modal popup window. I would like to let the user move the div around.

```
<style>
.popup{cursor:move;position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; margin:auto;}
</style>

<div id="modaldiv" style="popup">
   content goes here
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Which JavaScript framework are you using if any?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the basic idea then it will be like this.

1. A flag should be set when the mousedown occurs.
2. If the flag is set and mousemove occurs then change the position of the div according to the mouse position.
3. Unset the flag when mouseup occurs.

From this I don't think it is much harder to develop one.

If you need one based on a framework then this one will help you. Using jQuery

[**Draggable**](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/)

```
$("#modaldiv").draggable();
```

will make the div draggable.

Comment: You think it's really sexy using jquery+jqueryui to implement dragndrop :) ?

Comment: Why not? If you have a feature that deals with cross browser issues and best DOM traversal methods then go for it.